# Type error when trying to apply count() or len() functions on a column in a Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, typeerror, apply

```
data_sample['comment_len']=data_sample['Comment'].apply(lambda x: len(x)-x.count(" "))
data_sample.head()
```

I am just trying to get the length of the comment field by using this.
where data_sample is a data frame

```
def count_punc(text):
    count=sum(1 for char in text if char in string.punctuation)
    return round(count/(len(text)-text.count(" ")),3)*100
data_sample['pun%']=data_sample['Commentary'].apply(lambda x:count_punc(x))
data_sample.head()
```

Same error with this as well.

Comment: Please post the full error you get.

Comment: type error:cannot read property 'todstring' of source-map-support .. undefined and TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()